# extract paragraph match with words using sed or awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have file called "quota.txt" as below:

```
DISK_info_start:/usr
Disk: /usr
CURRENT=81
DISK_info_end:/usr

DISK_info_start:/usr/var
Disk: /usr/tmp
CURRENT=1
DISK_info_end:/usr/var
```

I have a variable as below:

```
entry=/usr
```

I want extract paragraph starting From DISK_info_start:$entry to DISK_info_end:$entry like this:

```
DISK_info_start:/usr
Disk: /usr
CURRENT=81
DISK_info_end:/usr
```

I tried this command:

```
sed -n "\|DISK_info_start:$entry$|,\|DISK_info_end:$lines$|p" quota.txt
```

but, it is not doing an exact match which is what i was looking for.

Can you tweak this command for me or provide an alternative?

Comment: Have you also defined the variable `$lines`?

Answer (score 2):

**Using `awk`:**

Use `awk` in paragraph mode:

```
awk -v RS= '/DISK_info_start\:\/usr\n/' quota.txt
```

If you match multiple paragraphs, add `-v ORS="\n\n"`, otherwise `awk` removes blank lines between the matches.

Note that you need `\n` instead of `$` to find the end of the line as the latter marks the end of the paragraph only.

If you need variables, make sure to quote the `/`:

```
entry=/usr
awk -v RS= "/DISK_info_start\:${entry//\//\\\/}\n/" quota.txt
```

---

**Using `perl`:**

`perl` has a paragraph mode, too (`-00`):

```
perl -00 -ne '/DISK_info_start\:\/usr\n/ && print' quota.txt
```

Add `| tr -s '\n'` to avoid printing the empty line at the end.

---

**Using `sed`:**

You could also use `sed` like this:

```
sed -n '/DISK_info_start:\/usr$/,/DISK_info_end:\/usr$/p' quota.txt
```

This will not really find *paragraphs* but from match to match.

Answer (score 1):

Try `awk`, it is good for text processing:

```
awk 'index($0, "DISK_info_start:"D"\n")==1' RS="" ORS="\n\n" D="/usr" quota.txt

DISK_info_start:/usr
Disk: /usr
CURRENT=81
DISK_info_end:/usr
```

Comment: +1 as it not only looks for match inside a paragraph but (at least as far as I understand it) that the match is in the first line of the paragraph.

Comment: Ah Ok! I misunderstand what you meant!

Answer (score -1):

You can try: `grep -A3 DISK_info_start:$entry quota.txt`

Comment: this works only if the paragraphs always have the same number of lines.